# Conservation of Hawking mass

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, mass, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Consider a spherically symmetric spacetime $M$ and define the (Hawking$^*$) mass through the equation $$1-\frac{2m}r=g^{ab}\partial_a\partial_b r.$$ I'm trying to prove that this implies
$$\partial_a m=r^2(T_{ab}-g_{ab}\text{tr}T)\partial^b r$$

The idea is not difficult: I differentiate the defining equation wrt $\partial_a$ and then do some computations using $G=T$ to get the desired RHS. Unfortunately, trying to do that results in me getting lost in a sea of indexes. Any suggestions on how to streamline the computation?

$*:$I don't think this is the standard definition of Hawking mass, but that's the name with which it was presented to me.

Comment: What is the dipendence of $m$ from your coordinates chart?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean ($m$ is a scalar, hence it does not depend on the choice of coordinates in any way, unless I'm missing something)

Comment: I mean if in your model m is a parameter or a scalar field, namely if it's $m$ or $m(t,r, ...)$

Comment: @LolloBoldo $m$ is in general a scalar field, defined by the first equation I've wrote